# Converting the data from file to float

Tags: android, audio-recording, typeconverter

So, I'm making the app in android and I wrote the code below to convert the audio data (in bytes) stored in the file to float. The thing is, I'm getting many NaN values and also, the other values just don't look like the actual audio data. I'm aware, that values larger than [255 255 127 127] overflow and result as NaN, but the audio is fine, when I play it.

```
private float[] FileToFloat(File file, int allSamples){
        byte[] byteBuffer = null;
        byteBuffer = new byte[allSamples];
        FileInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            in.read(byteBuffer);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteBuffer);

        float[] floatBuffer = new float[byteBuffer.length/4];

        for(int i = 0; i < floatBuffer.length; i++){
            floatBuffer[i] = bb.getFloat(i*4);}

        return(floatBuffer);
    }
```

EDIT: Maybe I should add header first?